# simpMessagingTemplate doesn't send message from client to server

Tags: java, stomp, spring-websocket, spring-messaging

I want to exchange messages by web sockets between 2 java apps.

I have the following server  configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/queue", "/topic");
        registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        //todo remove handshake handler when authorization is implemented
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*").setHandshakeHandler(new TestHandshakeHandler()).withSockJS();
    }
}
```

and inside class marked with `@Controller` I have wrote following theme:

```
@MessageMapping("/consumer/client/add")
public void addClientRequest(String msgReq) {
    logger.info(msgReq);
}
```

and inside clien I do connect and in sime bean I wrote following:

```
@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;
...
simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/app/consumer/client/add", new StubObject("message"));
```

But after sending from client method  `addClientRequest` doesn't invoke.

Please advice ways to troubleshot this issue.

Actually I don't understand issue. Maybe I send to wrong destination or I have issue with configuration or path is wrong or something else.

### P.S.

I know that I can `extend StompSessionHandlerAdapter`

and obtain session from there but looks like it is the bad style and should be another way to achieve it

### P.S.2

Inside class `WebSocketTcpConnectionHandlerAdapter`(inner class inside  `WebSocketStompClient`) I see `private volatile WebSocketSession session;`

I want to obtain this object to send messages

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it was designed to be used like this.

I think you must use a specific websocket client. This one for exemple :
http://www.programmingforliving.com/2013/08/jsr-356-java-api-for-websocket-client-api.html

This code :

```
@MessageMapping("/consumer/client/add")
public void addClientRequest(String msgReq) {
    logger.info(msgReq);
}
```

Will NOT connect to a websocket client and wait to have messages. It expect a client to connect throught it and send messages.